{"the request was aborted: the connection was closed unexpectedly."}. I got this message when all api in for loop
the first request i=1 is done but the next is getting this message:

{"the request was aborted: the connection was closed unexpectedly."}.

Here is my code
        for (var i = 1; i <= 4; i++)
    {
        var token = GetToken();
        string token_cookie = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["token_cookie"].ToString();
        var request = System.Net.WebRequest.Create(url + "/Revenue/GetList") as System.Net.HttpWebRequest;
        request.Method = "POST";
        request.UserAgent = "api-explorer-client";
        request.ContentType = "application/json";
        request.Headers["Cookie"] = token_cookie;
        request.Headers["Authorization"] = "Bearer " + token;

        string body = "{" + "\n " + "\"DateFrom\": \"" + "2024-09-01" + "\","
                  + "\n " + "\"DateTo\": \"" + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd") + "\","
                  + "\n " + "\"BranchID\": \"" + "0" + "\","
                  + "\n " + "\"DataType\": \"" + "all" + "\","
                  + "\n " + "\"PagingNumber\": \"" + 1.ToString() + "" + "\""
                  + "\n " + "}";

        byte[] postBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(body);
        //request.ContentLength = postBytes.Length;
        using (Stream stream = request.GetRequestStream())
        {
            stream.Write(postBytes, 0, postBytes.Length);//error here
        }
        string responseContent = "";
        using (HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
        {
            using (StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
            {
                responseContent = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
                RevenueList revenueList = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RevenueList>(responseContent);
                DataTable RevList = new DataTable();
                RevList = ToDataTable<RevenueListData>(revenueList.Data);
                           
                InsertBulkTable(RevList, "RevenueList");
                //currentPage++;
                streamReader.Close();
            }
        }
        request.Abort();
    }
}

i have also use another way but still got the message

I doubt you can reuse the request object - especially once it has been aborted. Which leads to the question: Why do you abort in the first place? Why don't you use HttpClient? Or even one of the fine Rest-Client Nugets?

FYI, this is a horrible way to generate JSON

i try HttpClient but it still get the same message

as pointed put, that code is weird because you are initializing the request outside the loop and also you are not dealing with the response at all like if you were preparing the job in advance. If that looks what I think, you should instead make a new instance of HttpWebRequest at each iteration.. and if you need to see the response you should also process request.GetResponse() at each iteration. Plus the json could be better crafted serializing an object instead of concatenating strings

yes, i use HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse() below that code. I can see the response but after the first loop (i=1), it stops here:stream.Write(postBytes, 0, postBytes.Length);

did you understand the previous comment? did you try to create the request inside the loop instead of doing it before the loop even begins? you are doing it 4 times.. each time you need a new request!

yes, i have tried doing it both inside and outside the loop

you should update the question showing the most updated code that includes also how you are creating the request object.

it gets the exect result in debug but not release

I advise you to use an HTTPClient, I made a version of your code that could work with it.
If you are not familliar with How to Post trough HTTPClient go read this
public class SendFourRequest()
{
    private readonly HttpClient _client;

    private string address = "https://localhost:3333/api" // Choose the target address of your client

    public SendFourRequest(HttpClient httpClient)
    {
        _client = httpClient;
    }

    public Task sendRequestsAsync()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
        {

            // This create a model with all the propertiew wou wanted
            var bodyContent = new RequestBodyModel()
            {
                DateFrom = DateTime.Parse("2024-09-01"),
                DateTo = DateTime.Now(),
                PagingNumber = i
            };

            // creation of the request
            var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, address);
            // Adding the body as a jsonContent
            request.Content = JsonContent.Create(bodyContent);

            var response = await _client.SendAsync(request);
            // Here you can check the response if wanted
        }
    }

    private class RequestBodyModel()
    {
        public DateTime DateFrom { get; set; }
        public DateTime DateTo { get; set; }
        public int BranchID { get; set; } = 0
        public string DataType { get; set; } = "all"
        public int PagingNumber { get; set; }
    }
}

The HTTPClient is in my case a Parameter but you can create one in the class. If you need to add cookie to it, go look how to set Cookie on HTTPClient

when use httpclient, i had set bearer token to it
request.Headers.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", token); and the token work in postman but in the code it return 401 message
